# readdir(3) strange behavior : finding non existing files in /dev/

Tags: c, implementation, ls, readdir

I'm using `opendir` / `readdir` / `closedir` to reproduce a program similar to ls, it went pretty well until I tried to `ls "/dev/"` when it comes to `/dev/fd/` with the recursive options, it find more files than it actually exists, those are not hidden files (I mean `.` commencing files).

The true `ls` give me :

```
"/dev/fd/ :"
"0 1 2 3"
```

Mine too.
But, the thing is that in `gdb`, it find 3 more files that are 4, 5 and 6. I heard that `gdb` create its own environment so let's forget this.

When I try `ls "/dev/fd/" -R` the true `ls` stops immediately the listing while my program gives:

```
"/dev/fd/3:"

"/dev/fd/3/3/"

"/dev/fd/3/3/......../10"
```

`stat` return -1 after 40 files at least but the execution continues: segmentation fault.

In my computer, `/dev/fd/3/` and so are symbolic links, the macro `S_ISDIR` returns me 0 on the existing files but on the non existing files like: "/dev/fd/6/" it return 1...

I wanted to know why my program goes wrong while the true `ls` doesn't, I noticed that `ls` use `stat64` in my computer but when I do it still goes wrong.. it also use `fstat64`, `futex` and others syscall that I don't know.

I can show you some sample of my codes or detail a bit more it's really hard to explain for me I'm sorry for that.

PS: I don't get that statement in the `readdir` manpage:

> The data returned by `readdir` may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `readdir` for the same directory stream

Comment: You do understand that the files under `/dev` are really pseudofiles, right?  In particular, the files under `/dev/fd` correspond to your currently open file descriptors, and so the very act of opening a file descriptor to read a directory (via `opendir(2)`) changes the directory contents.

Comment: @Adam: This should be an answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot I should get more reading about filesystems and fix that issue by forcing non-reading of these files!

Answer (score 0):

> PS : I don't get that statement in the readdir manpage : "The data
>   returned by readdir may be overwritten by subsequent calls to readdir
>   for the same directory stream"

What they are basically saying is that the function is not re-entrant, and that the pointer returned by `readdir` shouldn't simply be cached as a unique value, as the underlying data that is being pointed to will change the next time you call the `readdir` function.  Basically they are allowing for implementations to either define statically allocated data that can be recycled by the function, or dynamic memory managed by the OS, so that the caller of `readdir` does not have to worry about managing the memory pointed to by the return value of `readdir`.  For instance, for a sample function like:

```
int* my_sample_increment()
{
    static int val = 0;
    val++;

    return &val;
}
```

if you were to-do something like

```
int* int_ptr_1 = my_sample_increment();
int* int_ptr_2 = my_sample_increment();
```

Then both `int_ptr_1` and `int_ptr_2` will point to the same value, and in this case it will be the value `1`.  Each pointer won't be pointing to a unique integer value.

So the same is true with `readdir`.  You cannot simply call `readdir` and store the pointer being returned, expecting to use it at a later date without the data that is being pointed to being modified by any subsequent calls to `readdir` between the time you saved the pointer, and the time you use it.  If you need such functionality, that is what the re-entrant version, `readdir_r` is for.

Comment: `Then both int_ptr_1 and int_ptr_2 will point to the same value, and in this case it will be the value 1.`  Close but very wrong. They will both point to '2' because it was called twice. Don't know who up voted something so wrong. Another stackoverflow anomaly, I'm sure.